# Delete data from SQL Tables

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I have 10 tables , say Table_1,Table_2,Table_3,Table_4 ...,Table_10.. I have to delete data from all the tables except Table_4. Is there any single line query to do it.(Using 'LIKE','IN' etc) "Delete * from tablename like Table_ where Table NOT IN ('Table_4')"..

Comment: What database? I haven't thought it through yet, but you might be able to get the table names from the schema and then do... something with them.

Comment: does my link helped you?

Answer (score 1):

If the number of tables exceeds 10, you don't want to list all tables in the delete statement. You should stick to the catalog and use a cursor:

```
declare @table nvarchar(max)
delcare @cur cursor

set @cur = cursor fast_forward for
  select name
  from sys.tables
  where name like 'Table_%'
  and name not like 'Table_4'

open @cur
fetch next from @cur into @table

while(@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
  sp_executesql 'DELETE FROM ' + @table

  fetch next from @cur into @table

end
close @cur
deallocate @cur
```

---

Edit: this answer is for MS SQL only :)

Comment: It's not your's "**fault**" but it seems that writing the tables names is better... Less writing, More Readability, Works with every DB. =)

Comment: And if there are 10000 tables? :-)

Comment: So you would have a lot more problems then delete their data... **lol**

Answer (score 0):

```
use [db_name]

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

select @SQL = 
(select ';
DELETE FROM ' + quotename(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + 
quotename(TABLE_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
and TABLE_NAME not in ('mytab1', 'mytab2')

ORDER BY Table_Schema, TABLE_NAME
FOR XML PATH(''), type).value ('.','nvarchar(max)')

print @SQL -- verify
```

It will create query for delete and use this query delete the table u required and skip u not required.

Answer (score -1):

write a delete query with out Table_4

```
delete from Table_1,Table_2,Table_3,Table_5,......Table10
```

Comment: what if you have thousands of tables?? will you keep on writing it manually?

Comment: here there is only ten tables so i suggested

Comment: if I say I have 1000 tables and say what is your suggestion?

Comment: must use a T SQL for that purpose